# Listview for SQL lite

Tags: android, sql, listview

I was following a school tutorial for sql lite, and the output was a list of buttons. Is it possible to output this to a ListView instead?
I've tried googling and youtube but somehow  the tutorial I was following seems to have more files?
Confused newbie here!

Thanks in advance!

This code appears in the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
private void ShowExistingIdeas() {
        Idea[] ideas = new Ideas(this).getAllIdeas();
        if(ideas != null && ideas.length > 0)
        {
            for(int index = 0; index < ideas.length; index++)
            {
                Button ideaButton = new Button(this);
                ideaButton.setText(ideas[index].getTitle());
                final int id = ideas[index].getId();
                ideaButton.setTag(id);              
                ideaButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, 
                                EditIdeaActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("id", id);
                        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                    }           
                });

//!!! The bit I'm trying to change. the xml with LinearLayout1 is completely empty****
                ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1)).
                addView(ideaButton);
            }
        }
    }
```

For your reference - the Ideas file

```
public class Ideas {
    private Idea[] ideas;
    private Context context;

    public Ideas(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Idea[] getAllIdeas() {
        return getIdeasWithKeyword(null);
    }

    public Idea[] getIdeasWithKeyword(String keyword) {
        ideas = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = new DbHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
        String where = null;
        String[] whereArgs = null;
        if (keyword != null) {
            where = DbHelper.COL_TITLE + " LIKE '%?%' OR " + DbHelper.COL_DESC
                    + " LIKE '%?%'";
            whereArgs = new String[] { keyword };
        }
        Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_IDEAS, DbHelper.COLUMNS, where,
                whereArgs, null, null, null);
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            ideas = new Idea[c.getCount()];
            boolean hasMore = true;
            for (int index = 0; hasMore; hasMore = c.moveToNext(), index++) {
                int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COL_ID));
                String title = c
                        .getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COL_TITLE));
                String description = c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COL_DESC));
                int priority = c
                        .getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COL_PRIORITY));

                ideas[index] = new Idea(id, title, description, priority);
            }
        }

        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();

        return ideas;
    }
    public Idea getIdea(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = new DbHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_IDEAS, DbHelper.COLUMNS, "_id = "
                + id, null, null, null, null);
        Idea idea = null;
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COL_TITLE));
            String description = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COL_DESC));
            int priority = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COL_PRIORITY));

            idea = new Idea(id, title, description, priority);
        }

        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();

        return idea;
    }

    public void addIdea(Idea idea) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = new DbHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DbHelper.COL_TITLE, idea.getTitle());
        values.put(DbHelper.COL_DESC, idea.getDescription());
        values.put(DbHelper.COL_PRIORITY, idea.getPriority());
        db.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_IDEAS, null, values);

        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }

    public void deleteIdea(int ideaId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = new DbHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_IDEAS, DbHelper.COL_ID + "=" + ideaId, null);

        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at using an Adapter to populate your listview. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: Hi Blundell, I'm still absolutely clueless, the page doesn't really help me.

Comment: Maybe you should start here then http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html